# Mass, density and gravity for 2D SPH

Tags: gravity, mass, density

Having previously only worked with 3D sph, the 2d case is confusing me.
The concept of mass and density as well as gravity is not easily converted, as I see it.

As an example in 3D I take 1000 particles each having a mass of earthMass/1000 and distributed in a sphere of one earth radius. I calculate density by summing over all particles with a poly6 kernel normalized for 3d. The density is about 5000 kg/m^3 as expected.

Then I make this 2D by placing the same particles on a disk with one earth radius and sum using a poly6 kernel normalized for 2d. The density is very high now. In the order of 1E+15 kg/m^2.

Using such a value with my equation of state obviously does me no good.

I realize as much as that the mass I am inputting is essentially a dimensionless density integrated over x and y and z in 3d, where I should perhaps use a mass with is derived from the density integrated over only x and y, since this is 2d.

I then try to fix my mass by doing
mass2d=cubeRoot(mass3d)^2

When I do that, I get sensible densities around 5000 (kg/m^2??), and all is well...

but now the question is how I should deal with gravitational attraction between particles.

If I calculate the acceleration on one particle from the attraction of another (identical) particle, I do accelation=G*neighborParticleMass/r^2
this acceleration is now less than in 3d, since the mass is scaled down.
I then realize that where gravity diminishes relative to r^2 in 3d (sphere surface area), it should be relative to r in 2d (circle circumference).

This leads me to try accelation=G*neighborParticleMass/r
which still does not yield the same acceleration as in 3d, so that is still wrong.

Edit:
Tried thinking more in terms of force density and rewrote the acceleration to be based on mass1d=cubeRoot(mass3d) and mass2d=cubeRoot(mass3d)^2 like so
acceleration = (mass2d *mass2d / r^2) / mass1d
and this actually seems to always give the expected acceleration, but I am not entirely sure I understand what I just did, and why I end up using r^2 and not r as I just argued that I should.

I have been looking far and wide for papers dealing with how you set up a 2d initial state and how you deal with the quantities, that we only intuitively understand in 3d, in 2d, but with no luck. Is a mass even a meaningful concept in 2d? Is a density kg/m^2 and should it be the same numerical value as in 3d?

I am starting to wonder if this is so simple and obvious that no one bothers explaining it, or if I am having a blockage in my thought patterns.

I would really appreciate it if someone in here could try to explain how these forces and quantities are to be understood in 2d. I might add that I later tried thinking about everything as my 2d scene extruded in a third dimension, so a circle is a cylinder and a smoothing kernel essentially becomes a fuzzy cylinder, but I am not sure that is the way to go. It only seemed to confuse me more.

Comment: SPH = Smoothed-particle hydrodynamics?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Should have specified. I guess the core of the question is equally relevant for other methods, though.

Comment: Are you trying to work out the physics in 2 dimensions or the physics of a thin disk? It's probably the latter, I suppose, since gravity in 2 dimensions makes little physical sense for most applications.

Comment: If it helps, I still used $\rho=M/\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$ for my densities in my 2d Cartesian hydrodynamic simulations.

Comment: If you're looking for a really stable 2D SPH, take a look here: http://www.ann.jussieu.fr/frey/papers/levelsets/Clavet%20S.,%20Particle-based%20viscoelastic%20fluid%20simulation.pdf

Comment: As to 2D vs thin disk, I am wondering that myself now. I wanted to model simplified 2D planetary collisions and make it 2D to be able to get higher resolution, but I am slowly realizing that (non thin) 3D physics doesn't have a correct 2D representation. As an example the pressure towards the planet core will grow at a different rate in 3D and 2D. I have made 2D SPH before, but always using non-real materials, so I could just tune the parameters to get plausible behavior.